# Acces denied with File.WriteAllText in UWP app, but not in console app

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to write a file from a UWP i'm developing. But i keep getting an acces denied error.

I've tried:
Create a console app to write a file using the same filepath and this works.
Resetting windwows rights (done by windows domain admin).
Using different locations. This doesnt help.
I've set Visual Studio start as admin. This doesnt help either.

errormessage:

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> 'C:\Users\reinder\source\repos\UWPTeamAdministration\UWPTeamAdministration\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\entrypoint\players.json'
> is denied.\r\n   at
> System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)\r\n
> at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
> share, FileOptions options)\r\n   at System.IO.File

I really dont know where to go from here. It doesnt seem to me that it is a permissions issue. From what i read i understand by setting VS to start as admin ensures that the app i'm developing also is run in admin mode.

Any ideas?

I'have editted the question because the problem description seems slightly different then in my original post.

Comment: Make sure that the file is not being used by another process.

Comment: What the actual filesystem permissions for the file are? Are you able to write into this file with something like `notepad`?

Comment: @Serg. In the folder im trying to use i can create a file. Also i can edit the file in notepad. The accessdenied error only occurs when i try to write from the app im developping in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect to be able to write to the application folder. Typically apps are installed at locations that do not have write access.  If this is a file that you want to reuse then look at some of the other ["special" folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0#system-environment-specialfolder-applicationdata) that you could use (most likely `ApplicationData`).

Note that in any case you should use a sub-folder specific to your app since other apps can read/write to these folders as well.

Comment: Hi D Stanley, thank you for your answer. In the app i was developing i changed the location where the file should be written. I've hardcoded the path in the app to try to write to a location, from within this app, but i could not succeed. Just to be sure ive created a new console app, and from within this app i am able to write to a folder. So I'm not sure where i went wrong in the original app. I will use your suggestion and make a folder in the applicationdata folder as you suggested. This seems good practice to me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I need to post this or not. Maybe other new programmers encounter this same problem and can use the info.

It seems to me and correct me if im wrong that reading and writing files from an UWP app are restricted to certain folders. Also the methods used to do this are async methods.

I wasn't aware of the differences between a console app and UWP app at the time I asked.

I found the information on the websites below useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_file_management.htm#

Comment: Hi Reinder. It is good to give additional information but don't just add the link to an article on the web because it will erode over time. Just add the conclusions you found in the article on StackOverflow.